# Sorting a Hashmap by key, where key is a Pair of dates

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I've got a Hashmap like this:

```
Map<Pair<Date1, Date2>, Pair<DoesntMatter1, DoesntMatter2>> dates = new HashMap<>();
```

I want to sort that Hashmap at first by Date1 (ascending/chronological) and when Date1 dates are equal, then by Date2.
How to do it in a proper and efficient way?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Do you mean you want to end up with a list of the map entries sorted by their keys, with each key sorted first by Date1 then by Date2?

Comment: This is not a help forum, and you are expected to demonstrate some research effort before asking questions here. Update your question with a _specific_ problem you have when trying to sort the HashMap.

Comment: HashMaps should not be sorted by any value of the key, except the hashing algorithm delivers already such a value, what would be a quite bad hashing algorithm - perhaps start [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)

Comment: Write a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) for `Pair`.

Comment: Just don't use a `HashMap`, use a `TreeMap`.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are several ways. Given two records (classes would also work).

```
record Pair<T> (T getItem1, T getItem2) {
}
record OtherObject() {}
```

The first simply establishes a `TreeMap` as suggested by [Louis Wasserman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/869736/louis-wasserman) in the comments. A comparator first compares the first item of the pair, and, if equal, the second item.  To resolve object inference issues, the first comparison uses a lambda.  The next comparison can then use a method reference.

```
Comparator<Pair<LocalDate>> comp = Comparator.comparing(
                    (Pair<LocalDate> p) -> p.getItem1())
                    .thenComparing(Pair::getItem2);
```

Now establish the `TreeMap` using the comparator.

```
NavigableMap<Pair<LocalDate>, Pair<OtherObject>> navigableMap = new TreeMap<>(comp);
```

The second way simply sorts the map entries based on the map key and places them in a list.  The first item the comparator is a `keyExtractor`, the return type of which is `Pair<LocalDate>` used in the comparisons.

```
List<Entry<Pair<LocalDate>,Pair<OtherObject>>> entryList = 
      someMap.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Entry::getKey,
               Comparator.comparing(
                    (Pair<LocalDate> p) -> p.getItem1())
                    .thenComparing(Pair::getItem2))).toList();
```

Note:  `TreeMap` implements `NavigableMap` which extends `SortedMap` which extends `Map`